# How many eulerian circuits are in $K_{2,n}$ ?

Tags: graph-theory

Hello I have been asked to find a formula of how many different Euler circuits or as it also called eulerian cycles are in $K_{2,n}$. when $n$ is an even number ofcourse otherwise there won't be any eulerian circuits.

for example in $K_{2,2}$ you have vertices $a$ $b$ $c$ $d$ so there is only one cycle possible, in other words $adbca$ is the same as $cbdac$.

thanks from advance :)

Comment: I have no idea, well I could find 3, but maybe there are more...

Comment: well I got to a formula that sounds very logical to me which is (n-1)! because lets assume the 2 vertices are called a and b so it will show a (n/2 +1) times and b n/2 times like this: a_b_a_b..._b_a so in the _ you can fill each one of the n vertices. now you can order them in n! different ways inside the _, but in order to prevent the same cirlcles t be counted I devided by n, which makes it (n-1)! what do you think?

Comment: I think you nailed it! Yes, $(n-1)!$, the number of circular permutations of $n$ things.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is always good to have someone that can verify your work :)